# Redux middleware - Hook into action properties

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using Redux Promise Middleware and writing my action creators like this

```
export const getProject = () => ({
  type: "GET_PROJECT",
  payload: axios.get(process.env.SERVICE_URL + '/project/')
})
```

so that _FULFILLED and _REJECTED are appended automatically. This works fine.
Before using Redux Promise Middleware I was approaching my actions using dispatch inside the action itself, this way:

```
export function fetchTypes(){
 return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(process.env.SERVICE_URL + "/kinds/", {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.jwt
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_TYPES_FULFILLED", payload: response.data })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_TYPES_REJECTED", payload: err })
    })
  }
}
```

Much more verbose and repetitive. The problem with this approach is that I have to append the header on every action I create. What I am trying to do now is to write a middleware to update the payload and attach the JWT token to the API request so that I don't have to do it in every action creator, and check for token expiration. Is that feasible? I have read blogs and posts about middlewares but cannot find a way to hook into the request and add a property before calling next(action). 
Or maybe I am simply approaching the problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate file called `api.js` for example. There you describe your API functions, like `fetchKinds` and etc. Your action functions shouldn't contain API logic, they are for dispatching correct actions.

```
// api.js
class Api {
  _checkTokenExpiration () {
    // Throw error if expired
  }

  _getAuthHeaders () {
    this._checkTokenExpiration()
    return {
      'Authorization': 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.jwt
    }
  }

  fetchKinds () {
    return axios.get(process.env.SERVICE_URL + "/kinds/", {
      headers: this._getAuthHeaders()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err
    })
  }
}

export default new Api()



// actions
import api from './path/to/api.js'

export function fetchTypes(){
  return function(dispatch) {
     api.fetchKinds()
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_TYPES_FULFILLED", payload: response.data })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_TYPES_REJECTED", payload: err })
      })
  }
}
```